# Can I keep UserId in User.Identity ? MVC4 SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I wonder if SimpleMembership keeps UserId somewhere, or if not, how to force it to keep, once derived data.

I have simple action:

```
    [Authorize(Roles="User")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var ownerId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        return View()
    }
```

And my MiniProfiler says:

```
 DECLARE @0 nvarchar(4) = N'NICK'
 SELECT [UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = @0)   

 DECLARE @0 int = 2
 SELECT r.RoleName FROM webpages_UsersInRoles u, webpages_Roles r Where 
 (u.UserId = @0 and u.RoleId = r.RoleId) GROUP BY RoleName 

 DECLARE @0 nvarchar(4) = N'NICK'
 SELECT [UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = @0)
```

So, I have duplicated query for UserId - first to get the role, second by calling `WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);`. Is there a smart way to save UserId somewhere after calling [Authorize] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually wrap my users profiles in a session variable.

```
 public static userProfile UserInfo
 {
     get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] as userProfile; }
     set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] = value; }
 }
```

after the user logins in query the `UserProfile` table and do

```
UserInfo = QueryAsClass; //you need to map your sql to an object
```

once there you can access it any time by doing

```
UserInfo.userId
```

I have the `userProfile` table as an object class in my application

**Edit**

I have this code that gets executed after a user logins

```
using (var db = new DBEntities())
    {
        var userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        if (userId == -1) return;
        SessionHelpers.UserInfo = db.userProfiles.Single(x => x.userId == userId);
    }
```

I'm using EF5 and I have the `userProfile` table in my model, so you'll need to adapt this part if you're not using EF.

When I need the `userId` I just do `SessionHelpers.UserInfo.userId`. This let's me get all of the users profile info whenever I need it without requerying the database.

Of course if you **change** something in the user's profile you will need to update your session variable as well.

You may need to have more advanced logic and check that the session isn't null (which I'm doing elsewhere).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is still duplicated query in your app, but just after login action. Are you using WebSecurity.Login() to log in ?

Comment: check my edit and see if that helps you. I didn't see the edit to your comment. Yes, I'm using `WebSecurity.Login()`. In that sense I suppose I am doing a double query

Comment: I like this solution. I would have vote up, but my reputation is too low ;) I will be disappointed if there is no way to use data derived by Authorize filter.

Comment: if this worked for you, you should select this answer by clicking the green check